# Can't do anything in git bash

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

When I first downloaded git, I made a username and a password. But then I didn't do anything on it and now I have to clone a project from gitlab but I don't remember my password and keep getting a fatal error and it says authetication denied. I tried to edit my password in credential manager but it didn't work, I also tried to remove it in credential manager but that also didn't work. And I can't find anything about changing my password. What do I do?

Edit: I tried to edit/remove my password by going to credential manager>windows credentials> git:https://git.fhict.nl and click edit to change my password or click remove and than try to clone the project again. When I removed it, I have to enter my username and password again, but the password is always wrong.

And when I try this docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html
I first have to enter gitlab-rails console -e production it just tells me "command not found".

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html

Comment: "does not work" is not an accurate description of your problem. What is the exact error you're getting ? How exactly did you try to change/delete your password in windows credential manager ? What happened exactly when you tried that ? ...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove username and password from ~/.git-credentials and re run to submit new password.
And i suggest store it globally so config it:
`git config --global credential.helper store`

and also:

```
git config --global user.name "your username"

git config --global user.password "your password"
```

Comment: when I enter ~/.git-credentials it says "no such file or directory"?